# Android - D-Pad Navigation and Button Effects

Tags: java, android, user-interface, google-tv, d-pad

I am developing an application to be used in an Android TV environment. I am having a problem about how to implement this using the D-Pad navigation.

I want to achieve this effect.

[image]

But I am having problems like:

- how could I resize the ImageView at run-time?
- how to have a hovered-state ImageView?
- how to move the hovered button according to your d-pad input?

  Currently this is my what I have done.

[image]

I implemented this using horizontal linear layout and ImageViews.
Thank you

Comment: So the question is, how to animate the movement of the icons and the dynamic resizing of the imageview when they're selected and deselected, in a "not-reinvent-the-wheel" manner.

Comment: Yes, because I have no idea how to do it. Especially the hovered state. Also, if you have any good resources please do share. Thanks